# How do I define the fargate task definition health check to run a custom script on a windows container?

Tags: windows, docker, aws-fargate

I created a fargate task definition for a windows container.
I observed in the fargate documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html) that the health check is defined in the examples as a curl against local host.
I found documentation elsewhere that suggested it would be possible to use a custom script to check the health of a container.
I would like to execute a custom python script for the healthcheck of my windows container.

I created a healthcheck.py script:
simplified:

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
  exit(0)
```

I have tried defining the health check as the following (none of which worked):

- ["CMD-SHELL", "python healthcheck.py"]
- ["CMD-SHELL", "python healthcheck.py", "exit %ERRORLEVEL%"]
- ["CMD-SHELL", "python healthcheck.py; exit %ERRORLEVEL%"]

Comment: When you say they didn't work, did you get any error messages or anything? Also, that's just the ECS way of configuring a standard Docker health check. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck You should be able to work with that locally until you get it working, eliminating AWS/Fargate from the equation.

Comment: It shows the pending status for tasks (not success or failed). So is your suggestion to add the same command to the HealthCheck setting in dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, add it to your dockerfile, or docker-compose file if you have that, and test it locally until you get it running locally without issues. Then take whatever worked and configure ECS with that. I'm just saying it's so much easier to test and debug this sort of thing locally than trying to test it by slowly deploying to AWS over and over.

Comment: I tried using the ["CMD_SHELL", "python healthcheck.py"] version in my dockerfile, and when I started it locally and ran docker ps, the status column shows "Up x minutes (healthy)", but when I re deployed the fargate task def with that same health check cmd, it still is showing perpetual pending state.  Do you have any ideas for what to check?

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions. Maybe use `ecs exec` to get into the container running on Fargate and see if you can run that same `python healthcheck.py` successfully from there, or if it gives any errors.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I really appreciate your help :)